# Dynamically change the size of table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a loop structure which performs certain calculations and writes the results in some matrix $M$. When certain condition is satisfied the loop stops. Let's assume that this happens after $T$ iterations. Then, for the purposes of the problem I am considering, the necessary dimensions of $M$ are $d \times d$, where $d= \sum_{i=1}^{T+1} n^i$ and $n$ is a constant from the given problem considered (typically n=2,3,4). For example if $n=2$ and we know that the loop will finish after two iterations, we would have that $d=14$ and I would need a matrix $M$ that is $14\times 14$.

My issue is that since I do not know in advance when the loop is going to finish, I can not allocate in advance a size to the matrix $M$, so I have to assign something large to $d$ by guessing and hope the loop will finish before it runs out of space. I pre-allocate $M$ by:

```
M = ConstantArray[0, {d, d}]
```

So the question is, can I do this dynamically? In other words, can I increase the size of the matrix $M$ at each iteration without losing the previously written elements and how?

I can imagine that one could create a new matrix at each iteration of the appropriate size and copy the elements from previous iterations into it. Would that be efficient? How can it be done efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Just create a new matrix every time instead of put the new data into a fixed size table.

Comment: How do I copy efficiently all the elements of the previous matrix to the new one?

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you write down your actual problem, someone can help you find a solution that fits Mathematica's style better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to expand a matrix array by adding rows and columns, but for this application, making a new matrix and copying the old matrix to the new one will work. First, make a sample matrix.

```
SeedRandom[12]
d = 4;
m = RandomInteger[9, {d, d}];
m // MatrixForm
```

${\small\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
 9 & 7 & 3 & 1 \\
 7 & 0 & 9 & 5 \\
 4 & 6 & 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)}$

To make a new matrix that’s twice as large, for example, make a new matrix with `ConstantArray`, and copy matrix `m`. This fast and flexible as long as the new matrix is larger than the dimensions of `m`. It also works with matrices that aren’t square.

```
n = ConstantArray[0, {2 d, 2 d}];
(n[[ ;; #1, ;; #2]] = m) &@@ Dimensions@m;
n // MatrixForm
```

${\small\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 2 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 9 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 0 & 9 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 6 & 7 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)}$

Avoid using `ConstantArray` with `SparseArray`, although this method is slower.

```
n = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> m}, {2 d, 2 d}];
```

The results are the same.